# Localization Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I'm creating a localization for one of my Mac Apps to French, and I was curious if the keyboard shortcuts are named the same as they are in English? For example, "Nouveau (+)" would mean New (+), but what about the tab key? "Modifier (tab)" or should I convert the word tab to french? I'm not sure how apple names keys internationally? Any help or resources for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm French, and I think I could help you.

In French, "tab key" is "touche Tab" or "touche Tabulation".

Comment: Hi! Thank you! Do you have an email or way to contact you? I wish we had messages on here. I can pay you to do testing for the French version of my app??

Comment: You're welcome ! This is my email :http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k=01uB3yArTYSlNlO9ZxAAhuWQ==&c=_iJpsmSfX5soYOm19_xjcttChmzZT6U9JCv4ZrqNNdw=

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/localization/

and check out macrumors:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=399436

This should help... straight from the source. There are also a few companies that localize your applications if you are willing to pay for the service.